# Unable to use ifstream::operator>> using ifstream reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using C++11.

`std::ifstream` inherits from `std::istream`, so it should theoretically be capable of doing all the same things, but this does not seem to be the case.

I can define the same function in two ways:

```
void parse(std::ifstream &file) {
        for (std::string word; file >> word; );
}

void parse(std::istream &file) {
        for (std::string word; file >> word; );
}
```

When an `istream` is used, there is no error.

When I use `ifstream`, this error is returned from both g++ and clang++ (with slight variation):

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') and 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>'))
        for (std::string word; file >> word; ) {
                               ~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

I could use an `istream&` and use polymorphism to pass in an `ifstream&`, but I would prefer not to, and I would like to figure why this happens.

Comment: Hi vadix, welcome to SO! Questions about a build problem should always include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in addition to the full compilation error; please edit that in. It's impossible to diagnose problems otherwise. It might easily be a missing `#include` problem, for example.

Comment: And, to stress my earlier comment, just adding the relevant headers [works](http://ideone.com/UHv4jY). So either you're missing some, or there's a problem in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Ahh, that was indeed the issue. I will be sure to add all lines necessary to reproduce the issue next time. Thanks!